# How to use form values from a JSP file into <sql:query> tag in another JSP file?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I get the below error:
I am able to see the user input but the sql is not taking in the value?

**The error is as below:**

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException:
SELECT SOURCE AS source FROM flyaway.flightdetails
WHERE source= Delhi;
: Unknown column 'Delhi' in 'where clause'

**my index.jsp code are as below:**

```
<form action="ValidationFilter" method="get">
    Enter the source: <input type="text" name="source"><br>
    Enter the destination: <input type="text" name="destination"><br>
    Enter departure date: <input type="date" name="departure"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**my flightList.jsp are as follows:**

```
<sql:setDataSource
        var="myDB"
        driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flyaway?useSSL=false"
        user="root" password="1Leanest!"
/>

<%
     String source = request.getParameter("source");
     String destination = request.getParameter("destination");
%>


<sql:query var="listItems" dataSource="${myDB}">
        SELECT * FROM flyaway.flightdetails
        WHERE SOURCE= <%=source %>;
</sql:query>
```

I wanted to filter from the database in SOURCE column based on the user input from the form, but i get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the value in single quotes

```
WHERE SOURCE= '<%=source%>';
```

but having sql in a jsp is ugly.  Better to have a proper servlet/preparedStatement etc.

Comment: Amazing it worked!!!! Thank you soo much for your feedback. I am new in web development so this is my thought process for now. I will note down to use servlet/preparedStatement.